# CSS position text relatively to image

Tags: css

I am trying to position the text in a span on the bottom-right corner of an image which will be added dynamically, so the image may or may not take 100% of its container's width to keep its aspect ratio and stay within its container's canvas.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AbdelrahmanHafez/pen/BZWBVm/)

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ekz5.jpg)

The issue here is that the text is positioned relatively to the image-container not the image itself, and the image doesn't always take 100% of the width.

How can I keep the text always on the bottom-right of the image -no matter what its dimensions are- itself, not the container?

HTML:

```
<div class="slider_wrapper">
<div class="report">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/057739911161ece76a09b16617b92e72.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="report-image">
        <span class="name">John Doe</span>
    </div>
    <p class="report-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, id quisquam error, laborum officiis ea quod voluptates tempore, repellendus temporibus assumenda optio qui! Est distinctio numquam, quia quidem placeat repudiandae.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider_wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    /*height: 300px;*/
    margin: 40px auto;
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.report-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

span.name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.report-caption {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.35em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the blue border to span the full width of the parent, add a parent to the `img` and text, set to `display: inline-block` and move `text-align: center` from the paragraph to the parent that wraps your image container and paragraph to center the new `inline-block` image container and paragraph.

```css
.slider_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  /*height: 300px;*/
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.report-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span.name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.report-caption {
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 1.35em;
}

.report {
  text-align: center;
}

.image-holder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_wrapper">
    <div class="report">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/057739911161ece76a09b16617b92e72.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="report-image">
            <span class="name">John Doe</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="report-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, id quisquam error, laborum officiis ea quod voluptates tempore, repellendus temporibus assumenda optio qui! Est distinctio numquam, quia quidem placeat repudiandae.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the border doesn't need to expand the full width of the parent, you can just set `.image-container` to `inline-block` and move `text-align: center` to the parent that wraps `.image-container` and the paragraph to center them both.

```css
.slider_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  /*height: 300px;*/
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.report-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span.name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.report-caption {
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 1.35em;
}

.report {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_wrapper">
    <div class="report">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/057739911161ece76a09b16617b92e72.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="report-image">
            <span class="name">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <p class="report-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, id quisquam error, laborum officiis ea quod voluptates tempore, repellendus temporibus assumenda optio qui! Est distinctio numquam, quia quidem placeat repudiandae.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a wrapping div to the image:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
     <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/057739911161ece76a09b16617b92e72.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="report-image">
    <span class="name">John Doe</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then css:

```
.image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That conflicts with the "dynamic" part, it would force a horizontal image to take 50% of the container's width, while I want it to take 100% of the container's width.